Jupyter lab file explorer not showing .so files
I am running jupyter lab 3.6.5 in a Docker. When I open the file explorer (file browser) in jupyter lab, I can navigate through a mounted folder that is located on my local machine (Windows 11) and shared with the Docker (Ubuntu 22.04) that runs the jupyter lab.
All files and folder show up correctly apart from .so files. They do not show up in the file explorer. When I remove the .so extension they reappear but as soon as the .so extension is added again they disappear from the file explorer.
I have turned on "show hidden files" to see if this was the issue, but it did not help.
Does anyone have any idea how to make the .so file show up in the file explorer?

There is an according issue on GitHub. The solution from there is

jupyter-server's contents manager has ContentsManager.hide_globs
attribute and configuration option.
Default: ['__pycache__', '*.pyc', '*.pyo', '.DS_Store', '*.so', '*.dyl...
Glob patterns to hide in file and directory listings.

You would need to modify the c.ContentsManager.hide_globs option in
jupyter_server_config.py or pass via a command line argument (like
--ContentsManager.hide_globs='[]').

I've solved this problem a little differently. Instead of using jupyter_server_config.py I've changed ~/.jupyter/jupyter_server_config.json. The final file is:
{
  "ServerApp": {
    "password": "..."
  },
  "ContentsManager": {
    "allow_hidden": true,
    "hide_globs": []
  }
}

